# How to automate try.. catch

Tags: c++, exception

In an attempt to make demos small and simple, I wrote a function that handles all the errors that could happen. All the user has to do is write an object which inherits from GLWin, and pass it to the static init method. So main is simple, just one line, with the error handling being done by the static init function. However, for the first time I had an error in the constructor of the object, and realized that this system fails to catch those.

Can you think of a nice way to write my standard error handling so it does not have to be written every time in main? I would like to effectively have main written for me every time, possibly with different parameters in the constructor.

```
void GLWin::init(GLWin* w) {
  try {
    w->init();
    ...

  } catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << e.what() << '\n';
  }
}

int main() {
  GLWin::init(new MyDemo());
}
```

another example showing that the object may take parameters

```
int main() {
  GLWin::init(new MyMap("mapfile.shp"));
}
```

A suggestion has been made to use variadic template arguments, but I do not understand how to make it work.

If I write:

```
template<typename T, class... Args>
void init(Args... data) {
  try {
    setupfunctions();
    GLWin* w = new T(data...);

    cleanupfunctions();

  } catch (exception& e) { 
  }
}
```

Question is how does the compiler realize which class T should be?

If I write:

```
class A : public GLWin {
public:
  A(const char filename[]);
};

int main() {
  GLWin::init("myfile.txt");
}
```

How do I apply class A as the template T?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is what you would want but wouldn't `template<class T,class... Args> T* init(Args... data) try { return new T(data...) } catch (exception& e) {  }` work? (Obviously you don't have to return T* but can use it later on)

Comment: Currently, you require `main()` to pass a (pointer to) an object to the `init()` function, which requires the object to be constructed BEFORE calling `init()`, so `init()` CANNOT catch exceptions due to object construction failing.  Alternatives include changing the `init()` function so it accepts arguments that it uses to construct the object (and your original problem if construction of arguments can fail) or providing a function that `init()` calls to construct the object (since the `init()` function can control *when* it calls that function, and catch any exceptions it might throw).

Comment: Right! Variadic args. I will do it.

Comment: Ok, not clear on how the variadic args would work. I am editing the question

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me. Why objects? Why inheritance? Just use functions. `handleErrorsIn([](){action1(); action2();});`